# swiping pagination

Tags: swipe, photoswipe

There are a lot of jQuery image gallery plugins and swipe gesture ones for mobile website.

I want to combine two of them on my website. there's no problem using one but if I try to use two at a page. It doesn't seem to work well. Probably conflict.

I use [wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) which is great for thumbnail list on mobile. I want to apply finger swipe paging to this image list.

I could creat a list page with thumbnails...

Now I just want to swipe for next page for more images.

The similar sample is here:

http://m.search.naver.com/search.naver?sm=mtb_hty.top&where=m_image&query=Amanda+Seyfried

Comment: Do you have a question?  What does this have to do with Swing?

Comment: Sorry.. I meant Swiping.